# Python 3.4 : cStringIO vs. StringIO

Tags: python-3.x, import

## QUESTION

I am returning an ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'.  Unfortunately cStringIO doesn't exist anymore and I need to use StringIO as a replacement.  How can I do this?

```
import edgar
import ftplib
from io import StringIO 

ftp = ftplib.FTP(edgar.FTP_ADDR)
ftp.login()
try:
   edgar.download_all(ftp, "/tmp")
except Exception as e:
   print(e)
finally:
   ftp.close()
```

## OUTPUT

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/local/lib/ana/lib/python3.4/site-         packages/edgar/downloader.py", line 5, in <module>
from cStringIO import StringIO
ImportError: No module named 'cStringIO'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/aranjohn/PycharmProjects/edgar/secEd.py", line 1, in     <module>
import edgar
File "/usr/local/lib/ana/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/edgar/__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
from .downloader import FTP_ADDR, file_list, download, download_all
File "/usr/local/lib/ana/lib/python3.4/site-  packages/edgar/downloader.py", line 7, in <module>
from StringIO import StringIO
ImportError: No module named 'StringIO'

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`StringIO` no longer exists in 3.x. Use either `io.StringIO` for text or `io.BytesIO` for bytes.